# Bootstrap input file event removing data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-file-input

I'm using [Bootstrap FileInput](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) and it is really cool :)

I've got a problem with some events. I want to know how could I detect when I press on "Remove" button after submitting a file. Here is a pic of what I mean:

[image: remove button]

I've used "**fileremoved**", "**filedeleted**", "**filepredelete**", "**filebeforedelete**",... events (anything about "remove" or "detele"), but they don't work.

What's the event I'm looking for? Am I missing anything?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Here is my little JS code for the events:

```
$('#file_upload').on('filebatchuploadcomplete', function() {
    console.log("I have pressed the upload button"); // --- Ok, it works!! :)
    // More stuff here...
});

$('#file_upload').on('fileremoved', function() {
    console.log("I have pressed the remove button"); // --- Never shown!! :(
    // More stuff here...
});
```

Comment: How are you testing if the event is triggered? Can you replicate this on jsfiddle or similar?

Comment: @IvanS95 it's just a small code. I've updated the post, you can see it above. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Does the remove button actually delete the file?

Comment: No, it doesn't delete the file and it doesn't clean the file list on screen (what I just really want).

Comment: One week later... nobody knows :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bootstrap FileInput newest version, the remove event is ***fileclear*** or ***filecleard*** (https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-events#fileclear).

- fileclear: This event is triggered when the file input remove button or preview window close icon is pressed for clearing the file preview
- filecleard: This event is triggered after the files in the preview are cleared.

Ex: 
`$('#input-id').on('fileclear', function(event) {
    console.log("fileclear");
});`